# Responsive Design loading (max-width: 800px) as default layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am coding responsive site, at the moment I have done 2 CSS files  `scree_style.css` and `screen_layout_medium.css` I have written CSS for `<header>` section only for medium screens that is mentioned below.

This is how I linked them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  @media="only screen and(min-width:501px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="css/screen_layout_medium.css"  />
```

now after i wrote css for header section  for `screen_layout_medium.css`  this loads as default layout even if my browser is in full width  .

CSS for Header section for `screen_layout_medium.css`

```
header { height:200px; background:url(images/banner_medium.jpg) no-repeat 90% 0px;}
header a.logo { width:115px; height:70px; top:20px;right:20px;background:url(images/logo_medium.png) ; }
```

And styles for default CSS

```
 header  { height:275px ; background:url(images/banner_large.jpg) no-repeat right 0px;}
 header a.logo {width:150px ; height:85px ; top:28px; right:30px; background:url(images/logo_large.png) no-repeat ; }
```

what's the reason that its not loading `scree_style.css` as default layout  please help me with it.

Comment: the attribute in your link tag should be media="" not @media=""

Comment: then  it does not load css for 800 px width if i re-size browser to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@` before `media` in second `<link>` and put space between `and` parenthesis
:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="css/screen_layout_medium.css"  />
```

Sample (resize right column to see if it works): http://jsfiddle.net/4gP4M/